# Install pgAdmin III on Windows 7 without administrator rights

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-installer, pgadmin3

I'm trying to install pgAdmin III, using the v1.20.0 package from [pgadmin.org](http://www.pgadmin.org/download/windows.php). I found a few sources that suggest I should be able to install it for the current user only without having to provide the administrator password, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

[This mailing list item](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BANLkTimHUFk9CZQKigHcvFd1Om39nfnKnA@mail.gmail.com) says, of the v1.12.3 package:

> We don't set any properties that should force a per-machine
>   installation as far as I can see (we certainly don't force ALLUSERS
>   on). You might try installing form the command line with a command
>   like this:
>
> *msiexec* /i pgadmin3.msi *ALLUSERS*=""
>
> That should run the installer but for it into per-user mode.

In [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7649579/2359271), the OP comments:

> I used ALLUSERS=2 and MSIINTSTALLPERUSER=1

So, reading the linked pages in that Q&A (but only understanding some of what I was reading), I tried a few variations:

```
PS C:\Users\ath\Downloads\pgadmin3-1.20.0> msiexec /i pgadmin3.msi ALLUSERS=2
PS C:\Users\ath\Downloads\pgadmin3-1.20.0> msiexec /i pgadmin3.msi ALLUSERS=""
PS C:\Users\ath\Downloads\pgadmin3-1.20.0> msiexec /i pgadmin3.msi ALLUSERS="" MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1
```

In each case, the final "Install" button has an administrator shield icon and when I click it to proceed, the password dialog pops up; canceling out of the dialog halts the installation.

I'm not sure if I'm using `msiexec` wrong or if these workarounds simply don't work for this combination of software and OS versions.

How can I install pgAdmin III on Windows 7 without administrator rights? Is there any reason to believe this isn't possible, other than my failure so far?

Comment: Still having this problem with v1.22.1.

Answer (score 1):

I recently was able to run pgadmin 4 on a win 10 machine without installing it (and without admin rights) by first installing it on another PC on which i did have admin rights.  Then i copied the install directory.  Finally i had to chase down vcredist140.dll and msvcp140.dll and copy them into the install directory on the target machine.  I am sure not everything functions as normal that way, but it was sufficient for me to query the database.

i suspect a similar technique would work for win 7.